# Gremlin Groovy Java Finding shortest Path + basic connectivity

Tags: java, groovy, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have java application from which I'm calling a groovy class to compute the shortest path between 2 vertices in a graph.

**Java:**

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      TinkerGraph g = new TinkerGraph();
      Vertex src = null;
      src = g.addVertex(null);
      src.setProperty("name",1); 
      src.setProperty("Type", "switch");
      Vertex src1 = null;
      src1 = g.addVertex(null);
      src1.setProperty("name",2);
      src1.setProperty("Type", "switch");
      Vertex src2 = null;
      src2 = g.addVertex(null);
      src2.setProperty("name",3);
      src2.setProperty("Type", "switch");
      Vertex src3 = null;
      src3 = g.addVertex(null);
      src3.setProperty("name",4);
      src3.setProperty("Type", "switch");
      Edge e=null;
      e=g.addEdge(null, src, src1, "connects");
      Edge e1=null;
      e1= g.addEdge(null, src1, src2, "connects");
      Edge e2=null;
      e2= g.addEdge(null, src2, src3, "connects");
      System.out.println(GetRoute.getPathToHost(g));
   }
}
```

**Groovy:**

```
class GetRoute {
   static {
      Gremlin.load()
   }
   public static Map<Vertex, Integer> getPathToHost(TinkerGraph g) {
      g1.V[["name":1]].both.loop(2){!it.object.equals("name":4)}.Paths >> 1
   }
}
```

My question is:

1. First of all the query is wrong. I've computed a function in gremlinpipe+java but it's pretty huge and I'm try to find a easier way with groovy. How do I refine this query?
2. Lets say my query prints all the vertices in the path between 2 vertices then how do I store it in let say an Map array or how do I print it onto the console?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: I think you want loop(1). loop(2) takes you back to the starting point over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my Gremlin session:

```
gremlin> g = new TinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> src = g.addVertex(null)
==>v[0]
gremlin> src.setProperty("name",1) 
==>null
gremlin> src.setProperty("Type", "switch")
==>null
gremlin> src1 = g.addVertex(null)
==>v[1]
gremlin> src1.setProperty("name",2)
==>null
gremlin> src1.setProperty("Type", "switch")
==>null
gremlin> src2 = g.addVertex(null)
==>v[2]
gremlin> src2.setProperty("name",3)
==>null
gremlin> src2.setProperty("Type", "switch")
==>null
gremlin> src3 = g.addVertex(null)
==>v[3]
gremlin> src3.setProperty("name",4)
==>null
gremlin> src3.setProperty("Type", "switch")
==>null
gremlin> e=g.addEdge(null, src, src1, "connects")
==>e[4][0-connects->1]
gremlin> e1= g.addEdge(null, src1, src2, "connects")
==>e[5][1-connects->2]
gremlin> e2= g.addEdge(null, src2, src3, "connects")
==>e[6][2-connects->3]
gremlin> g.V.has('name',1).out.loop(1){it.object.name != 4 && it.loops < 5}{true}.path.filter{it.last().name == 4}
==>[v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3]]
```

The last line there calculates the path between 1 and 4.  You can read more about shortest path calculations with Gremlin in gremlindocs: http://gremlindocs.com/#recipes/shortest-path (please pardon the formatting...some dns issues are plaguing it atm)

I'm not sure how you would want that `Map` you asked for.  The List format seems good to me for a path, but I suppose if you wanted it keyed on the first vertex in the path, I guess you could just issue another tranform:

```
gremlin> g.V.has('name',1).out.loop(1){it.object.name != 4 && it.loops < 5}{true}.path.filter{it.last().name == 4}.transform{[(it.first()):it]}
==>{v[0]=[v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3]]}
```